# How to set up the authorization header for NTLM in Faraday

Tags: ruby, ntlm, faraday

I user Faraday Ruby library and don't understand how to set up authorization header for NTLM. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found [the article](https://dev.to/kopylov_vlad/ntlm-authentication-with-ruby-and-faraday-3lin) with the answer!